# Android TextView and Buttons not working in my app

Tags: android, class, button, textview, oncreate

I am learning Android and trying one simple Android app development, I got one demo code from my lecture and the teacher simply do the following:
There are 2 buttons, 1 textview. When touching button A, it will show "text A" in the textview, while touching button B, it will present "text B" in textview.

I followed the code and rewrote it, but i can't get the correct result when I ran with emulator.

When I touch either button, there's no content in the TextView. But my teacher's reference code works:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ActTwo extends Activity {

    private TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_two);
        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }

    public void report(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
            tv.setText(R.string.anrep);
        else
            tv.setText(R.string.iprep);
    }

}
```

How is `report(View v)` called? I can't understand how this class is called. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let your button know that, when pressed, `report()` should be called. This may be done through the `android:onClick` attribute of your button on your layout's XML:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/button_text"
 android:onClick="report" />
```

Or by code, attaching an `OnClickListener` to the button:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_two);
    button1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            report(v);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am used to iOS which would introduce IBAction. Wow, Android does it this way!

Answer (score 0):

You should implements the `View.OnClickListener`, and override that `OnClick` method. You also need to `setOnClickListener` on your buttons. So your code should be like:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ActTwo extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private TextView tv;
    private Button button1, button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_two);
        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
            tv.setText(R.string.anrep);
        else
            tv.setText(R.string.iprep);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class ActTwo extends Activity {

    private TextView tv;

    private Button button1, button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_two);
        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        button1 =(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
               report(v);
            }
        });
        button2 =(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2):
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
               report(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void report(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)
            tv.setText(R.string.anrep);
        else
            tv.setText(R.string.iprep);
    }

}
```